# Как сделать, чтобы при добавлении строки с уникальным полем второй раз, обновлялась имеющаяся строка?

Tags: mysql, sql

База mysql.
Есть таблица товаров. В таблице есть уникальное поле "артикул".
Пытаюсь добавить новую запись в таблицу, где уже есть товар с этим же артиклум. Естественно mysql ругается на уникальность поля "артикул"...

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при добавлении новой строки, строка где уже есть аналогичный артикул удалялась и таким образом "артикул" оставался уникальным?

Comment: был уже такой вопрос где-то, если коротко: [`insert... on duplicate key update...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Конкретно в MySQL есть REPLACE: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/REPLACE.html

Comment: автор, примите во внимание, что `replace` удаляет текущую и вставляет новую, т.е., как следствие, расходуются id и если на текущую запись ссылаются другие - будут проблемы. Кроме того, `replace` не поможет, если вам надо сохранять "создателя" записи и ее "обновлятеля". Т.е. при `replace` всегда "создателем" будет "обновлятель". `on duplicate key update` избавлен от таких проблем: id он сохраняет, можно указать, что обновляете вы только "обновлятеля" и т.д.

Comment: @Alex, в первом комменте я уже писал - такой вопрос был, т.е. надо не ответы писать, а закрывать как дубликат. Тем более, автор уже два возможных варианта получил и узнал чем один отличается от другого, поэтому на закрытие вопрос он не обидится.